# Symfony Basic API Http Authentication

Tags: php, rest, symfony1

Can someone point me in the right direction in regards to making an api use basic http authentication?

I am creating a restful api with symfony but would like to require users to be logged in to get certain data. I would also like many of these methods be dependent on the the username in the authentication process in order to get some of the data (using the username from the credentials to get all of a users friends)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function send401() {
    $realm = "Credentials for site xxx";
    header("HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required")
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="'.$realm.'"');
    die();
}


if (!array_key_exists('PHP_AUTH_USER',$_SERVER) ||
        !array_key_exists('PHP_AUTH_PW',$_SERVER)) {
    send401();
}
else {
    $res = authenticate_user($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
    if (!$res)
        send401();
}
```

The username is stored in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`.

Comment: This is also possible with Symfony2 configuration. Search for `http_basic` and `stateless` on http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html . I'm not sure when this configuration-based approach was made possible with Symfony2.